# Setting up a static IP for Linux system (ubuntu 18.04 )

Tags: networking

FYI:

Our Linux system has a LAN port and WiFi.
Via LAN, it connects to Network 1; Via WiFi, it connects to Network 2 that has internet connectivity.

"Use this connection only for resources on this network" is enabled for Wired (LAN) connection.
Only after which, our linux system is able to get internet connectivity.

we wish to set static IP for our linux system. While trying to do that via settings -> IPV4 -> Set IP address, gateway IP address and network mask; But, unable to click on "Apply" button;
Only if the "Use this connection only for resources on this network" is unchecked, we are able to click on "Apply" button.

The problem is, if "Use this connection only for resources on this network" is unchecked, linux system does not able to get internet connectivity.

So, can anybody suggest us the procedure to set static IP for linux system, while "Use this connection only for resources on this network" is checked?

Comment: You have a "default" route which is currently pointing at Network 1, but you want it to point at Network 2. So you need to check "Use this connection only for resources on this network" for Network 1 and uncheck it for network 2.